# MySQL - Filter a table based based on location / distance - ST_Distance

Tags: polygon, mysql

I have table with `Polygon` geometries. I'd like to filter the table to include rows that are at a certain distance from a `Point` coordinate.

Here's a fiddle link for table schema, data etc.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c3c5863af9fe855491e4ef71f21a64b

Filter query based on proximity and distance.

```
select *
from geo
where st_distance(geometry, Point({lat},{lng})) <= {dist};
```

Basically, I'd to calculate the distance between a `Polygon` and `Point` and filter rows. Time it takes the query to run matters, so I am looking for a time-efficient solution.

Comment: There is no optimal solution to a generic point distance query -- It has to be calculated for all rows, which is expensive,  See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325886/whats-the-equivalent-of-st-dwithin-postgis-postgresql-for-mysql

Comment: @Vince how does `st_distance` calculate the distance between a `polygon` and `point` geometries? The so link is for calc. dist between `points`.

Comment: A guide 'Efficient Distance Querying in MySQL' https://aaronfrancis.com/2021/efficient-distance-querying-in-my-sql but postgres/postgis with indexing would be even faster.